# Start a session in MobaXterm from batch script

Tags: batch-file, session

When I had Windows 7, the following batch command opened MobaXterm, and inside, it opened a new tab (in addition to the home tab) that connected to a VM ('linux-server'):

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe" -newtab linux-server
```

Now, in Windows 10, the command does not work well. It opens MobaXterm, but does not open a session to the VM.

I tried to run the command from command-line, the result is the same.

My requests are:

- Opening a session to the VM in MobaXterm using batch command (the "home tab" that was opened in the past is unnecessary)
- I use private key to connect this session, for some reason, Moba does not save the passphrase for the private key, only the user's password. I would like to save the passphrase as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

From the [MobaTek Blog](https://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-command-lines/)

> `MobaXterm.exe -newtab ["<Command>"]`:
>
> This command can be used to start a new tab inside a running instance of MobaXterm (or start a new instance of MobaXterm if no other instance is running) and immediately execute a given MobaXterm command

So you would need to specify a ssh command to connect to your virtual machine.

You could also save the ssh connection (or any other connection type) as a "first level" bookmark and use the `bookmark`-command instead:

> `MobaXterm.exe -bookmark "<Bookmark_name>"`:
>
> This command can be used to start a bookmark by specifying its name.

In your case, the command would look like this, if your bookmark would be called "linux-server"

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe" -bookmark linux-server
```

Comment: How can I open `-newtab` with an ssh connection to a certain host, I can't find the documentation for the "<Command>" part.

Comment: The official Mobatek doku tells us (as you said), that it's not possible to invoke sessions in subfolder. But this isn't true. You can seperate the subfolder-text with \
Like: start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe" -bookmark "FirstFolder"\SubFolder\SubFoldert\"Name Of Bookmarked Session". Use "" to capsluate the text, If you have blanks in your Bookmarks. Like "My Session Name".

Comment: @nethero `-newtab "ssh username@server"` works for me

Answer (score 4):

I'm providing example usage for opening mobaxterm with specific command. Below is an example of opening a MobaXterm portable Personal edition in a newtab mode with SSH and a specified username.

```
MobaXterm_Personal_20.6.exe -newtab "ssh -l username 192.168.1.99"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this incase anyone else might be looking for something similar. This is a PowerShell script which is in my Autostart folder in windows 11.

This will Autostart MobaXTerm and open your connections in multiple Tabs and send the reattach command for screen

I have username and passwords stored in MobaXTerm so you might have to adjust using @Nadzri's answer.

```
# Path to MobaXterm executable
$mobaxtermPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe"

# Define a list of IP addresses and their corresponding users
$servers = @(
    @{ "IP"="192.168.*.*"; "User"="USERNAME"; "Command"="screen -rd" },
    @{ "IP"="192.168.*.*"; "User"="USERNAME"; "Command"="screen -rd" }
    # Add more servers as needed, Don't forget to adjust USERNAME and IP to fit your own.
)

# Start MobaXterm
Start-Process $mobaxtermPath

# Wait for MobaXterm to load
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

# Iterate over each server and open a new SSH session in a new tab
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $ip = $server.IP
    $user = $server.User
    $command = $server.Command

    # Construct the SSH command with the specific command to execute
    $sshCommand = "ssh -t $user@$ip '$command'"

    # Start a new tab with the SSH session
    Start-Process $mobaxtermPath -ArgumentList "-newtab `"$sshCommand`""
    
    # Optional: Adjust sleep if necessary to ensure tabs open correctly
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

I Hope this helps, Good Luck! :D